# Rails strong parameters: permitting nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Say I have controller `params` with the following structure:

```
{
  "foo" => {
    "id" => 123,
    "children" => {
      "0" => {
        "a" => "a"
      },
      "1" => {
        "b" => "b"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I permit all the data explicitly?  I don't want to permit arbitrary data at any point in the hierarchy.

I had expected this work:

```
params.require(:foo).permit(:id, children: { "0" => [:a], "1" => [:b] })
```

However, it returns:

```
{ "id" => 123, "children" => { "0" => {}, "1" => {} } }
```

How can I whitelist the permitted attributes for each child?

Comment: Oddly, I get the expected results when the child keys are non-numeric.  Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try square brackets instead of braces:

```
params.require(:foo).permit(
  :id,
  children: [
    "0": [:a],
    "1": [:b]
  ]
)
```

Comment: That does not work either.  That also returns `{"id"=>123, "children"=>{"0"=>{}, "1"=>{}}}` and prints two messages to the console: `Unpermitted parameter: :a
Unpermitted parameter: :b`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

params.require(:foo).permit(:id, :children => { :"0" => [:a], :"1" => [:b] })